# How to start Tomcat with a double-click icon?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have a web application containing jsp pages. I have created war file and deployed it. But now I want to create an icon on which if I double click it should start tomcat as well as start execution from the first jsp page. No need to start tomcat explicitly. I have created web application in eclipse. Is it possible to do something like this?

Can I prepare an exe that will start tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

startup.bat is not something you click on, it is something you call from a command line. If you certainly could do a "doucle-click to launch Tomcat" action, your question lets me think you're not familiar with command line programming and thus, probably don't have the skills to create it.

My advice is that should spend some time learning how to handle command line tools and then everything should be clear (on Mac, launch the "Terminal" app to get to the command line, on Windows, I can't remember)

Comment: I dont want to use any command line tool. I just want to create something like exe that will start tomcat and start executing my jsp page

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but I'm afraid you won't have the choice. Any executable that could help you would be a DOS script, that nobody can write for you because it probably depend on your environment.

Comment: But I want something like icon, so that user can run the application easily.

Comment: An icon is an image above an executable file... which should be a command line script...